# Can ring crown bottles be recapped?

Tags: bottling, capping, recapping

Can ring crown (pull off) bottless such as  these: [image: these] be recapped using a table top or bench bottle capper?

EDIT: Just to be clear, I mean capping the bottle with regular caps like these[image: caps], not not pull off caps.

EDIT2: I finally bought a capper and tried this. It worked!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give it a try-- fill a bottle with water, put a cap on, flip it upside down, and see if any water drips out.  If the cap makes a watertight seal, then the next time you're bottling fill a couple and see how they work out.

Comment: I have not started brewing or bought a capper yet. I bought a brewing kit and it came with plastic bottles. I did not want to use plastic bottles and i started to collect glass bottles. These were the cheapest. I will try to collect normal bottles from now on. I can not vote up yet, thanks for the answer.

Comment: If the water test works, fill them with soda water, turn the bottle upside down and give it a shake. That will prove if they seal.

Comment: maybe even fill with something carbonated to test it under pressure.  throw in a soda or something,  cap it and listen for it outgassing, or hold upside down.  if you're brave give it a shake.  the key being that beer will be pretty pressurized, so match that when testing.

Comment: Hopefully you'll be able to find some regular pop tops where you live.  FYI, if you're reusing commercial bottles* remember to avoid bottles that are twist-off.  Those can't be recapped, both because of the lip at the mouth of the bottle and the and because the glass is a lot thinner and can't stand up to the forces required to crimp the cap on.

*I don't know what imports are available where you live, but I've reused quite a few Hacker-Pschorr bottles, both the 330mL and 500mL bottles.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that it will work. The cap "tears" as you open it. But, as Herb said, give it a try!

Comment: I edited my question, can you please look at it?

Comment: Ahhh.... I have no idea. :) it looks like it might be the same size. So, still committing with Herb's answer, cap it and see.

Comment: If you do not have a capper, them maybe go to your local home brew shop and ask them to help you.

Comment: I'm living in Turkey, there are no local home brew shops here :( Homebrewing is not common here. Thanks for the answer, i can't vote up yet.

Comment: Maybe contact a local commercial brewer. Usually brewers are happy to chat and help people.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience yes they can, sometimes the top of the bottle can be strangely shaped and stop some cappers working but usually you are fine to recap with crowns for your home brew.